# In Angular 6, how can I create a link that adds a query parameter but doesn't change the (optional child) URL?

Tags: angular, routes

I have a route, let's call it Page, at the path `/page` with two child routes, like so:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'page', component: PageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: FooComponent },
      { path: 'bar', component: BarComponent }
    ]},
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

The PageComponent template contains a navbar with options and toggles that affect the data displayed in the child (either Foo or Bar which represent different views of my data).  Within that navbar, I have a toggle which sets a query parameter for customer type (wholesale, retail, or both), like so:

```
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-group-sm" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" [(ngModel)]="customer">
    <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-warning">
      <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="'retail'" routerLink="." [queryParams]="{customer:'retail'}" queryParamsHandling="merge"> Retail
    </label>
    <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-warning">
      <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="'wholesale'" routerLink="." [queryParams]="{customer:'wholesale'}" queryParamsHandling="merge"> Wholesale
    </label>
    <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-warning">
      <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="null" routerLink="." [queryParams]="{customer:null}" queryParamsHandling="merge"> Both
    </label>
  </div>
```

That's a lot of bootstrap stuff but the critical part for my current question is this part of each toggle:

```
routerLink="." [queryParams]="{customer:'retail'}" queryParamsHandling="merge"
```

Whether the user is looking at `/page` or `/page/bar` this adds `?customer=retail` to the end of the URL, which is just what I want.

**The problem is:** if the user is viewing `/page/bar`, clicking this link sets the root URL to `/page`, loading the FooComponent in the child outlet, which I don't want.

How can I keep the user at the same route he's currently viewing, while adding the query parameter that I want?  Is there a way of writing `routerLink` so it doesn't go anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the normal behavior of the rotuerLink to which you pass the dot.

You have two ways to reach your goal.

1) Intercept and change the routing into the component file or

2) pass to `routerLink="[bar]"` or foo..

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works.  I changed `routerLink="."` to `[routerLink]="null"` and it behaves as I want it to, keeping the user at the same endpoint while adding or changing query variables.

I'll hold off on marking this "correct" just in case someone has a better answer that explains why this works and/or whether there's a more "proper" way to accomplish this.